# EE3 core file entry tag

Tags: files, core, ee3

I'm getting an error with simple file entries tag:

> The following tag cannot be processed:
>
> {exp:file:entries}
>
> Please check that the ‘file’ module is installed and that ‘entries’ is an available method of the module

Is file entry tag not supported in EE3 core, or did I miss a step somewhere and did not enable something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else wondering EE3 DOES NOT include file tag. There is a bug submitted that is marked as "Fix in Upcoming Release"

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/file-entry-tage-does-not-work/

They probably just did not get round to implementing it. I wish the documentation indicated it. It's okay to roll out your features slowly, but it does not make sense to have documented feature/behavior missing in your release.

Answer (score 0):

This might be obvious, but did you go to "Add-ons" section in Control Panel and make sure "File" module is installed?

Comment: the add-on section shows about about 9 plugins, and some are installed and some not, but "File" is not on the list. the is a fresh install of EE3 Core.